# How to do string slicing in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, slice

This is a [Pig Latin translate practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin) in Ruby.

Why am I getting different results from these two versions of code? In other words, why is `word = word[i..-1]` not taking effect in the second code block?

```
def translate(input)
    output_array = input.split(" ").each do |word|

      i=0
      while !['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].include?(word[i])
        i += 1
      end

      unless i == 0 
        word << word[0..i-1]
        word[0..i-1] = ''
      end

      word << "ay"

  end
  return output_array.join(" ")
end

puts translate('apple')
puts translate('banana')
puts translate('trash')
puts translate('eat pie')
```

which outputs:

```
appleay
ananabay
ashtray
eatay iepay
```

And:

```
def translate(input)
    output_array = input.split(" ").each do |word|

      i=0
      while !['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].include?(word[i])
        i += 1
      end

      unless i == 0 
        word << word[0..i-1]
        word = word[i..-1]
      end

      word << "ay"

  end
  return output_array.join(" ")
end

puts translate('apple')
puts translate('banana')
puts translate('trash')
puts translate('eat pie')
```

prints out:

```
appleay
bananab
trashtr
eatay piep
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output_array = input.split(" ").each do |word|

  i=0
  while !['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].include?(word[i])
    i += 1
  end

  unless i == 0 
    word << word[0..i-1] # Good
    word = word[i..-1] # Bad
  end

  word << "ay"

end
```

The line

```
word << word[0..i-1]
```

changes the string in place, while

```
word = word[i..-1]
```

creates a new string and assigns the new string to `word`. Changing the new string does not affect the old string in the array, so the words in the array stay what they were after

```
word << word[0..i-1]
```

Do every modification in-place (like what you did in solution 1), or use [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-map) which is more Ruby-like.

This is off-topic, but your `while` loop can be replaced by

```
i = word.index(/[aeiou]/)
```

if you happen to know regular expressions.